# O365 Outlook addin - Automatic email resolve in compose mode

Tags: office-js

Is there a way, where I can convert the email address (simple string) to EmailAddressDetail in the compose mode automatically? Because when I send the email, and not all email is converted to EmailAddressDetail, these unconverted recipients doesn't get the mail, but the others does. I linked a picture, where the **example1@gmail.com** is an EmailAddressDetail, and the **example2@gmail.com** is not, and I want to convert the **example2** address to look like the **example1**.

I have tried to get the the value with the following method, but it only returns the **example1**:

```
Office.context.mailbox.item.bcc.getAsync(callback);

function callback(asyncResult) {
    var arrayOfBccRecipients = asyncResult.value;
}
```

[Picture about the examples](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gPYWF.png)

[Picture about the result of the getAsync](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gZ45f.png)

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please see "[ask]", "[Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648)" and "[MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)" and all their linked pages along with "[Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/128421)"
"[Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812)".

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set Compose recipients using EmailAddressDetails you can simply pass the fields needed in an array of JSON objects.

For instance:

```
Office.context.mailbox.item.bcc.addAsync
(
    [ 
      {
         displayName: "Contoso User",
         emailAddress: "user@contoso.com"
      }
    ],
    { "asyncContext" : null },
    function(asyncResult)
    {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(asyncResult));
    }
);
```

If you want to read the fields in EmailAddressDetails for getAsync, you can refer them by their field names like you shared in your 2nd picture.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I want to do the following:
The user writes an email, add the email address, but forget to "make it" to EmailAddressDetails.
So he wrote something like: example@gmail.com and doesn't click to the "Use this address:" and the email remains string, not EmailAddressDetails, and because of that, I cannot able to determinate the recipients, because the getAsync only gives back the "EmailAddressDetails" without the "string objects". So I doesn't get the "example@gmail.com" string, only an empty array. That's why I want to resolve the these emails somehow in the code.

Comment: Hey. Unfortunately, unresolved recipients can't be accessed by this API. We do acknowledge how this might be somehow confusing, but this is the case here. We thank you for reporting this issue and have put added an item on our backlog. However, we do not have any timelines to share at this point.